# How to export a Gnumeric table into Latex under Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: latex, gnumeric

According to the Gnumeric manual available at http://www.fifi.org/doc/gnumeric-doc/html/C/, Latex 2e is one of the supported file formats, available via the Save as... dialog.

Using Ubuntu 14.04 and having installed Gnumeric from the Ubuntu Software Center, I do not see the option to save as Latex in the File Type drop-down menu.

Answer (score 4):

This is not anymore in File/Save as, you need to use Data/Export Data/Export into Other Format...

Comment: Would help to specify which version you're referring to...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screenshot showing the location of 'export' in the menu system. Note the keyboard shortcut for repeating exports in the same format, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>].

[image]

The option to export to `Latex 2e` produces a standalone `.tex` file of the 'report' class, incorporating the packages `longtable` and `multirow`, which is too large to reproduce here.

This can be somewhat unwieldy, so if the final output is going to be `.tex` I have found it simplest to keep the formatting of the `gnumeric` table to a minimum (e.g. ignore column alignment, although date formatting *is* useful, as above) and export as `Latex 2e table fragment`, as below, which is rather 'bare bones'. Editing the `.tex` manually allows for the use of additional niceties like the package `booktabs`.

A better choice might be to export the table from Calc, using [Calc2LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179208/how-to-use-calc2latex) or similar. This should result in less work formatting the table correctly in `.tex`.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  This is a LaTeX2e table fragment exported from Gnumeric.        %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    &b  &c  &d\\
1   &ab &1  &1-Jan-2000\\
2   &cd &2  &1-Jan-2010\\
3   &ef &3  &1-Jan-2020\\
```